# Adding text/comments to Powerview

Tags: report, powerview

Does anybody know how to display some text or comments on a PowerView report for example to explain why a graph is what it is ? I do not want to export to PowerPoint and add a shape manually, I would like the text to display within the PowerView report (and being published in SharePoint) ?

Any idea or guidance welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Power View "Edit Report" view, you can add static components to your Power View report.  By static, I mean non-data-driven items, such as Text Boxes and Images.

The below image shows what this looks like in SharePoint 2013.

[image: The image illustrates a Power View, in Edit Mode in SharePoint 2013, with a Text Box added for annotation]